# How do I get the weather widget in the Notifications Center of the iPad?

Tags: ios, notifications, widgets

This is driving me crazy because I see this in notification center in a lot of a screenshots for iOS reviews:

[image]

What is the app that adds weather to the notification center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not available on iPad. It's an iPhone feature.

Comment: That is really annoying, I guess Apple assumes that people on a tablet don't give a crap about the weather.

Comment: I don't know how it works on iPhone, but the location is not always accessible even with the wifi connected.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same on the iPad, you'll need to jailbreak it and download an app called "Stock NC Widgets for iPad".

It doesn't appear to be working yet, but its what you are looking for.

Comment: @Emil, is Ask Different policy to advocate jailbreak as a solution?

Comment: @globalnomad The answer was only valid for jailbroken devices, so I edited to make sure that was obvious. Also, jailbreak solutions are welcomed in my opinion, per my interpretation of http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/is-asking-about-jailbreaking-with-another-os-on-or-off-topic :)

Comment: The original question didn't ask for jailbreak, hence the question. If the OP asked for jailbreak, then I see no issue. I've posted on [meta] to seek direction. :)

Comment: Does not seem to work for me as well: it crashes SpringBoard on my iPad 3 / iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your Settings -> Notifications -> Weather Widget.

Comment: Hmm, I am not seeing that anywhere under Notifications. This is under iOS 6 on an iPad.

Comment: I don't think it's available on the iPad. iPhone only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to jailbreak your ipad (use evasi0n) then load the app onto your iPad.

Follow the instructions here: 
http://www.sinfuliphone.com/showthread.php?p=953237

On iPad mini this worked fine, but iPad 3 it works with the caveat that the images for the multi-day forecast don't show.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/how-to-fix-weather-app-images-not-showing-on-ipad-3

Comment: Any confirmation that this works on iOS 6.0.1? For example, there is no `Weather.app` to link under `/Applications` so I have copied one from [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4a3rcqn0gwgu084/UEwyPeWtLU) – perhaps that is the reason why stocks app crashes SpringBoard and weather app does not display anything, only label "Weather".